# HTML Form Validation Multiple Zeros in Phone Number field

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

How can I create validation for my phone number field that prevents users just putting multiple zeros instead of an actual phone number?

To make it clear, I just want to prevent the user from entering multiple zeroes to circumvent the other validation in place. I don't really want to follow any sort of pattern as the site I am using it on is international so a variety of different phone numbers will be input...

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "tel" input the validation is implemented like all other html5 validations by the browser and not all of the handle everything the same (e.g. for the [email input the-art-of-web](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/) documents it). But you can specify a regex pattern with the [*pattern* attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) to meet your validation needs:

```
<input type="tel" name="country_code" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" />
```

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern) is at 84.96% globally. However, especially Android browser lacks it till version 4.4.4. Maybe you want to constitute a javascript based fallback for that if android is crucial (e.g. [pure javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp) or [any available library](https://www.google.de/?q=js%20form%20validator))